# Hotdog theme flair bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flair

Here is my “Hotdog” themed flair:

[image: Hotdog flair]

Notice that the Stack Overflow logo is almost invisible.
Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: An oversight, I'd say. The new logo and the old design clash rather violently.

Comment: I always thought the Hotdog theme was meant to clash with everything.

Comment: I wonder, how did it look like before the icon change of Stack Overflow?

Comment: @ShadowWizard here is how it looked [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gp8sn.png)

Comment: @HackerKarma so this issue was there all along, wonder why reported only now...

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, I knew it (many others probably)... it just a ignorance and partly due to we know why... but now that it's raised I wonder how can  it be solved without changing the logo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've implemented Ilmari Karonen's suggestion because it's the easiest to implement without extensive code changes: you just draw a rect of the same placement as the icon before drawing the icon. This only applies for Stack Overflow, and only for the hotdog theme.

It will be deployed in build 2870 for Stack Overflow, and build 3032 for SE.com (for network flair).

[image: Site flair]
[image: Network flair]

(Our internal dev instance is based on an old snapshot of Stack Overflow, which is why my rep is about 10k less than it actually is.)

Comment: Sorry, but I find it worse than what we had before. That yellow background is just too... intrusive. (Wish I had a better suggestion, but I'm not a designer :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard You do realise that hotdog is meant to be a "kitschy" design, right?

Comment: Yes, but still... even for a "kitschy" design, it just feels wrong in my eyes. Nothing personal! :-)

Comment: So... the yellow is sauce?

Comment: @United It's supposed to be reminiscent of mustard, but see also: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-tribute-to-the-windows-31-hot-dog-stand-color-scheme/

Answer (score 9):

Or just kill the hot dog theme. It was only funny for 2 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

Suggestion: use a bright yellow background for the site logo, like this:

[image: hotdog style stack overflow flair with yellow logo background]

The yellow is close enough in luminance to white that most site logos should be recognizable on it (the new SO logo is probably close to the worst case — it's not exactly high-contrast even on white), yet it still looks appropriately garish for the hotdog theme. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is to do something like this:

[image: Other flair option]

This is the Meta logo with colors inverted.

If the user wants a *meta* flair, the site logo could have:

```
M E
T A
```

to the left (in yellow of course).